# How to upgrade to Babel 7

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, webpack-4, babel-loader

I tried to upgrade Webpack and Babel to 4, 7 respectively but couldn’t make it work. Also the [official doc](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration) isn’t helping much with the upgrade.

I am getting following issue

> compiler error: ERROR in Cannot find module '@babel/core'  @ multi
> main

dependencies I am using:

```
"babel-core": "^6.26.3",
"babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"webpack": "^4.15.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Babel changed the name of the module `babel-core` to [@babel/core](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-core.html). Just run `npm install @babel/core`. This will install the latest version of Babel core.

Most of the packages in Babel has been renamed to follow the pattern `@babel/PACKAGE_NAME`. So if you want to upgrade, change the package names to follow the pattern and run `npm install`.

To upgrade to Babel 7 you can use this [migration guide](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration).

Answer (score 47):

Use [babel-upgrade](https://github.com/babel/babel-upgrade)

Tested on **node@10.15.3**, **npm@6.4.1** and **babel@7.4.0**

You can use following script. (npx on node 5+ only)

```
npx babel-upgrade --write
```

The --write flag writes the updates to your package.json and .babelrc.

You will end up with following modifications to *package.json*:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0"
}
```

*.babelrc*

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Out of the above plugins you need `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods` to make private properties work correctly if you choose to implement them.

If you are using eslint, dont forget to set your parser as *babel-eslint* like so in your *.eslintrc* file:

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
}
```

Comment: could this be valid also for babel.config as since some version that is the name instead of .babelrc?

Comment: @CarmineTambascia. Things slightly changed since v7.x.
Like the babel docs claim:
All Babel API options are allowed depending on your use case mentioned in the [configuration](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration) page.

Comment: this should be considered as an answer as well

Comment: Depending on your setup, you might also need "npm install @babel/runtime-corejs2 --save" - especially if you get an error such as "Cannot find module '@babel/runtime-corejs2/helpers/interopRequireDefault'" The above worked for me with the addition of this step.

Comment: This library seems dead.

Answer (score 9):

You can use babel-upgrade for smooth upgrading.

https://github.com/babel/babel-upgrade

You might need `npm prune` after that in order to discard outdated packages in node_modules.

EDIT:

When I tried babel-upgrade, babel and webpack config was not modified. so I had to change it manually. Here is the example.

.babelrc

```
"presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"]
```

webpack config

```
loader: 'babel-loader',
options: { presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/react']}
```