# Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined in reactjs when i use docker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, babeljs

my problem is that i am getting this error when i run my react-app with docker image. When i am not running my react app with docker image works fine. I have seen a lot of stuff on stack Overflow but none of this solved my problem.

I am using `babel version < 7` specific is `6.26.0`

I have tried to upgrade my `babel version` to 7 with this [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52157996/how-to-upgrade-to-babel-7), also i have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61755999/uncaught-referenceerror-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined-in-react) but it's not solve my problem.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: can you share your babel config file?  I would like to check your plugins and presets.

Comment: `{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread", "transform-object-assign",
    ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "style": true }]
    // ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "style": "css" }]
  ]
}`

Comment: just to make sure, can you add @babel/transform-runtime" in the plugins? at least this is how it worked on my side. And can you verify that you have the same node version onn docker and vice versa?

Comment: @BurakAyyildiz can you be more specific on how to add `@babel/transform-runtime` in the plugins. I `npm install` this but nothing show up in the `babelrc` file. Also you mean if i have the same version on my computer with the node version that i give to docker?

Comment: Yes correct, check the node versions on your local machine and the one on docker. e.g for the babelrc add it like this: {   "presets": [     "es2015",     "react",     "stage-2"   ],   "plugins": [  "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",   "transform-object-rest-spread", "transform-object-assign",     ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "style": true }]     // ["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "style": "css" }]   ] }

Comment: Yes i give the same `node version`, also i get this error when i change the `babelrc file`: `ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime" specified in "/web_app/.babelrc" at 0`

Comment: please install the package like: `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-runtime` and `npm install --save @babel/runtime`

Comment: @BurakAyyildiz now i am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined`

Comment: Now you have different errors, import other babel plugins. Look for solutions in the internet now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Burak Ayyildiz, i solve my problem. I just install `babel-plugin-transform-runtime` with this command: `npm i babel-plugin-transform-runtime` (I am using babel<7). Also on the `babelrc` file i add this on plugins: `"transform-runtime"`